# Run multiple Flask applications

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to run 2 Flask applications with DispatcherMiddleware but it's not working.

Here are my files:

hello_world_app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

bye_world_app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/bye")
def hello():
    return "Bye World!"
```

wsgi.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = DispatcherMiddleware(hello_app, bye_app)
    application.run()
```

I'm trying to run it like this:

> gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:9999 wsgi

And this is the error I get:

> Failed to find application: 'wsgi'

Thanks

Comment: It's working fine for me, what's your folder structure?

Comment: @Luis All 3 files are in the same folder.

Comment: And are you running gunicorn while inside that same folder?

Comment: Yes, in the same folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things:

- I don't think you need `__name__ == "__main__"` bit
- `DispatcherMiddleware` does not have a `run()` method
- You don't really need to run it, gunicorn will do it for you
- `DispatcherMiddleware` expects an app as the first argument and optionally a dict of `mounts`. I believe you can set root app to `None` if you so desire.

So I would try doing something like this:

```
# hello_world_app.py
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

# bye_world_app.py
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Bye World!"

# wsgi.py
from hello_world_app import app as hello_app
from bye_world_app import app as bye_app
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware

application = DispatcherMiddleware(None, {
    '/hello': hello_app,
    '/bye': bye_app,
})
```

Not sure if it's the absolute best way to do it, but it worked for me.

Comment: have documentation for dispatcher middleware?

Comment: @perymerdeka let me google that for you: https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/middleware/dispatcher/